# How to make UITableView scroll smoothly with calculating cell height with auto layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I define custom UITableViewCell in storyboard with autolayout, and I set the UITableView's rowHeight as UITableViewAutomaticDimension, all things go will.

Here I fetch more date I get a problem. if I scroll to the bottom of tableView, and then fetch more items to the date source of the tableview, reload tableView, and scroll up, when a new cell displayed, the tableView will jump, the cell which would scroll out of screen is jump to the screen. I want the tableView scroll smoothly.

How could I fix it?

Comment: You may find this post helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights. You might consider setting an estimated height w/ `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` before it's calculated.

Comment: Thank your for your help. Using estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath made the  jumping not so obviously. If I want to avoid the jumping, I should calculate the actual height of row.
The reason I using autolayout is  to avoid calculate the height...